# Pgsql search in json string

Tags: postgresql

I have small problem with search in pgsql json.

WHen i run my query:

```
SELECT * FROM dbname WHERE 
tresc::json->>'user' like '%login%'
order by id asc;
```

I have result:

{
"user": "mylogin",
"desc": {
"DestinationCode": "123232",
"String": "xxxxxxxxx",
"Service": "123"
}
}

It's work fine.
Now I need add second parametr: desc->service = 123 for example:

```
SELECT * FROM dbname WHERE 
tresc::json->>'user' like '%login%'
**and  tresc->>desc->service = 123**
order by id asc;
```

how can i make it?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

> ```
> json -> text → json
> jsonb -> text → jsonb    
>         Extracts JSON object field with the given key.
>         '{"a": {"b":"foo"}}'::json -> 'a' → {"b":"foo"}
> ```

> ```
> json ->> text → text
> jsonb ->> text → text
>     Extracts JSON object field with the given key, as text.
>     '{"a":1,"b":2}'::json ->> 'b' → 2
> ```

Solution using `->` operator

```
with d as (
 (select 1 as id, '{"user": "mylogin", "desc": {"DestinationCode": "123232", "String": "xxxxxxxxx", "Service": "123"}}'::jsonb as tresc)
  union 
 (select 2 as id, '{"user": "mylogin", "desc": {"DestinationCode": "123233", "String": "yyyyyyyyy", "Service": "321"}}'::jsonb as tresc)  
)

select id, 
  tresc, 
  tresc->'desc' as desc, 
  (tresc->'desc')->>'Service' as desc_service_text, 
  ((tresc->'desc')->>'Service')::integer as desc_service_integer
from d 
where tresc->>'user' like '%login%'
    -- and  tresc->>desc->service = 123
    and ((tresc->'desc')->>'Service')::integer = 123
order by id asc;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fOz1kM8r)